# From Voronoi tessellation to Shapely polygons

Tags: python, gis, voronoi, shapely

from a set of points I built the Voronoi tessellation using [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html):

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
vor = Voronoi(points)
```

Now I would like to build a [Polygon in Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#polygons) from the regions the Voronoi algorithm created. The problem is that the Polygon class requires a list of counter-clockwise vertices. Although I know how to [order these vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709283/how-can-i-sort-a-coordinate-list-for-a-rectangle-counterclockwise), I can't solve the problem because often this is my result:

[image]

(overlapping polygon). This is the code (ONE RANDOM EXAMPLE):

```
def order_vertices(l):
    mlat = sum(x[0] for x in l) / len(l)
    mlng = sum(x[1] for x in l) / len(l)

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709283/how-can-i-sort-a-coordinate-list-for-a-rectangle-counterclockwise
    def algo(x):
        return (math.atan2(x[0] - mlat, x[1] - mlng) + 2 * math.pi) % 2*math.pi

    l.sort(key=algo)
    return l

a = np.asarray(order_vertices([(9.258054711746084, 45.486245994138976),
 (9.239284166975443, 45.46805963143515),
 (9.271640747003861, 45.48987234571072),
 (9.25828782103321, 45.44377372506324),
 (9.253993275176263, 45.44484395950612),
 (9.250114174032936, 45.48417979682819)]))
plt.plot(a[:,0], a[:,1])
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: That doesn't look like a counterclockwise ordering of vertices. Are you sure you implemented the ordering algorithm properly?

Comment: @Kevin I think I implemented it correctly... I updated the question with an example

Comment: Is that the code that generated your graph? Or is it a separate example?

Comment: @Kevin that code generated the graph :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you're just after a collection of polygons you don't need to pre-order the point to build them.

The `scipy.spatial.Voronoi` object has a `ridge_vertices` attribute containing indices of vertices forming the lines of the Voronoi ridge. If the index is `-1` then the ridge goes to infinity.

First start with some random points to build the Voronoi object.

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
import shapely.geometry
import shapely.ops

points = np.random.random((10, 2))
vor = Voronoi(points)
voronoi_plot_2d(vor)
```

[image: Voronoi plot from scipy.spatial]

You can use this to build a collection of Shapely LineString objects.

```python
lines = [
    shapely.geometry.LineString(vor.vertices[line])
    for line in vor.ridge_vertices
    if -1 not in line
]
```

The `shapely.ops` module has a [`polygonize`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.polygonize) that returns a generator for Shapely Polygon objects.

```python
for poly in shapely.ops.polygonize(lines):
    #do something with each polygon
```

[image: Polygons from Voronoi with some sample points]

Or if you wanted a single polygon formed from the region enclosed by the Voronoi tesselation you can use the Shapely `unary_union` method:

```python
shapely.ops.unary_union(list(shapely.ops.polygonize(lines)))
```

[image: Merged Voronoi tesselation polygon]

Comment: How can you save the shapefile with the polygons?

Comment: @ValerioD.Ciotti Use `shapely.geometry.mapping` on the polygon(s) to cast them as [geojson](http://geojson.org/) objects, and then use a library like [fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) to write the geojson to a new shapefile. From there if you're stuck ask questions on [http://gis.stackexchange.com/](http://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ValerioD.Ciotti Or you can make `geopandas.GeoSeries` from the polygons and save it directly into shapefile.

Comment: You can also use the `fiona` library directly, which GeoPandas already depends on.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52727406/68063) for a way to handle the infinite Voronoi regions.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, it is because you have to rebuild the polygons from the resulting points correctly based on indexes. Although you have the solution, I thought I should mention there is also another pypi supported tesselation package called [Pytess](https://thepythongischallenge.wordpress.com/2015/06/25/pytess-a-convenient-gis-tesselator-package/) (Disclaimer: I am the package maintainer) where the voronoi function returns the voronoi polygons fully built for you.

Answer (score 0):

The library is able to generate ordered list of coordinates, you just need to make use of the index lists provided:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi

...

ids = np.array(my_points_list)
vor = Voronoi(points)
polygons = {}
for id, region_index in enumerate(vor.point_region):
    points = []
    for vertex_index in vor.regions[region_index]:
        if vertex_index != -1:  # the library uses this for infinity
            points.append(list(vor.vertices[vertex_index]))
    points.append(points[0])
    polygons[id]=points
```

each polygon in the `polygons` dictionary can be exported to geojson or brought into shapely and I was able to render them properly in QGIS

Answer (score -1):

The function you implemented (order_vertices() ), cannot work in your case, because it simply takes a already ordered sequence of coordinates, which builds a rectangle, and inverts the direction of the polygon (and maybe works only with rectangles...).
But you have a not ordered sequence of coordinates

Generally speaking, you can not build a polygon from a arbitrary sequence of not ordered vertices because there is no a unique solution for concave polygons, as showed in this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408711/4313133

However, if you are sure that your polygons are always convex, you can build a convex hull with this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15945375/4313133 (tested right now, it worked for me)

Probably you can build the convex hull with scipy as well, but I dint test it: [scipy.spatial.ConvexHull](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html)